# A PPA "source" only lists a subset of the available packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt

I added this PPA a long time ago but when I'm trying to install the `polo-file-manager` package from Tony George it wasn't available when doing an `apt install`, so I went and removed the PPA and then re-added it but the result is still the same.

(`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:teejee2008/ppa`)

When using a GUI tool like Synaptic or Muon, the PPA only shows `selene` and `timeshift`, not the complete list of packages or, for that matters, `polo-file-manager`.

`apt update` doesn't show any errors / warnings. the related gpg key is present in the apt folder.

What's happening here and how do I fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: This probably has to do with your Ubuntu version. What is your version?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is eoan (19.10), why would that be a problem?